# Firebase queryEqual to check child node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query a list of objects by their author id. Is this possible?

```
Programs
    program1
        authorId:  user1
    program2
        authorId:  system
```

I tried the following and it returns no results. If I comment out

```
FIRDatabase.database()
    .reference(withPath: "programs")
    .queryEqual(toValue: "system", childKey: "authorId")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. The `queryEqualToValue()` method with two parameters is really only useful when implementing pagination. To query a list by the value of a child property, use:

```
FIRDatabase.database()
    .reference(withPath: "programs")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "authorId")
    .queryEqual(toValue: "system")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this, hmmm so you can only query against what you sort by? because in the code I don't see defining a field to check for value `system`

Comment: Yes, you can only filter on the key/value/child you sort on. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data